# Use managers in Factory-Boy for models

Tags: python, django, testing, factory-boy

Use Factory-boy for retrieve operation without use the DB for testing case.

I have this simple model:

```
class Student(models.Model): 
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20) `
```

To get all: `Student.objects.all()`

With Factory-boy:

```
class StudentFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
```

Is there a way to make **StudentFactory.objects.all()** ?

When I call the method all() in my factory, I would like to return a list of QuerySet created by me. Example: [QuerySet_1, QuerySet_2] # Not Database.

With that, I can change my data from DB to memory in my test.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the methods [create_batch](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=create_batch#factory.create_batch) and [build_batch](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=create_batch#factory.build_batch), depending on whether you want to save the newly generated instances in the `test` database or not.

Here's an example which I copy-pasted and adapted [from factory-boy documentation](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#using-the-factories):

```py
# --- models.py

class StudentFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Student

# --- test_student_factory.py

from . import factories

def make_objects():
    factories.StudentFactory.create_batch(size=50)
```

Comment: yes, I can create in memory with the build methods... but what I need, it is a way to get the elements in memory: StudentFactory.objects.all()

Comment: One way to automatically keep track of all instances generated by `factory-boy` could be to override [FactoryOptions.instantiate()](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/blob/a2cd524382247988df9d730c09934d909e783534/factory/base.py#L311). But that seems to be overkill, isn't it a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)? Why don't you want to temporarily save your `Students` in a `test` database? You could even [define a specific database](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/orms.html#factory.django.DjangoOptions.database) for `StudentFactory` exclusively...